# Spring pattern validation using predefined validators on field that can be either Email or URL

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-validator

In my Spring application I'm trying to validate a field which can be either an email address OR a url (as non-standard as that is I know).

I'm looking to use the pre-defined validators @Email and @URL in some combination rather than using a massive regex or implementing my own validation methods. Here's what I'm trying:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{plugin.helpUrl.notEmpty}")
@Size(min = 3, max = 1000, message = "{plugin.helpUrl.invalidLength}")
@Email
@URL
private String helpUrl;
```

Of course if an email is input, the URL validator fails, and if a URL is input, the email validator fails. This behaviour does make sense, but I'm wondering if there's a way to use them in an OR fashion such as `@Email OR @URL`.

**Edit**: to clarify, I know there are ways to implement this validation by implementing validation interfaces, etc. The question I was hoping to answer is: can I use the predefined validators @Email and @URL to accomplish this. Clarifying this in the title.

Comment: Maybe find the implementation of both then make your own annotation which call both implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Create a utility super class ValidateField. Create two subclasses ValidateEmail and ValidateUrl that extend it and each have an annotation. Create each with the field to validate in the constructor. Catch the exceptions in the class you instantiate each from and set bools as to whether they're valid. If less than 2 exceptions are thrown, it's valid. Long winded but will achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@AssertTrue`. Implement this method in Request class. This method will be called to validate when you make a request.

```
@Valid
@AssertTrue
public boolean isValidEmailOrUrl(){
    if(new URLValidator().isValid(helpUrl,null) || new EmailValidator().isValid(helpUrl,null)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I clarified my question: looking to use \@Email, @\URL in a "OR" combination rather than the default "AND" combination. However this looks like a nice clean backup solution, thankyou.

Comment: if need and then add logic in method

Comment: Something seems wrong with that URLValidator class... `new URLValidator().isValid("http://www.nhl.com",null)` returns `false`